# XMLHttpRequest has a 200 status, but responseText is empty

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm making an XMLHttpRequest to upload an image file. I can see that it's a 200 status and my image is uploading onto my service. However, when I use the code below to get the responseText (which should include information such as: URL for my image, filename, timestamps, image dimensions, etc.), it comes back as an empty string:

```
  //...

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', props);
  data.append('upload_preset', uploadPreset);
  data.append('api_key', apiKey);

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', cloudinaryURL, true);
  const sendImage = xhr.send(data);
  const imageResponse = xhr.responseText;
  console.log('Response: ', imageResponse);
```

Prints this to the console:

```
Response:
```

Any idea why this is happening / how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure the error is in js part?

Comment: What are you returning server side?

Comment: `responseText` is the output text of page you are calling

Comment: @RugDealer this is being handled within a Redux action, so doesn't touch the server at all.

Comment: @k102 Yes, because it does work. I can see the image uploaded and am getting a 200 ok status back. This is the only file in my app that makes the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using XMLHttpRequest in asynchronous mode:

```
xhr.open('POST', cloudinaryURL, true);
```

But your code is designed for synchronous mode:

```
xhr.open('POST', cloudinaryURL, false);
```

In asynchronous mode, `xhr.send()` will return immediately without actually processing the request. So, `xhr.responseText` hasn't been populated yet when you try to access it.

Comment: Yes, this solved my issue! Thanks so much for pointing out the problem and explaining. Appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. As a side note, I would in fact recommend to use asynchronous mode to avoid browser unresponsiveness. You can see a live example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first).

Comment: Great, thanks for the example. So it looks like I can run this asynchronously and get access to responseText if readyState == 4 and status == 200. Very good to know. Thank you!!